# How to use onSubmitEditing in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to use *onKeyPress*, but since android doesnt get *hard keyboard* input, i want to use **onSubmitEditing**,

I have two *TextInputs*, what I want to do is that when I press on *Enter* when i am in *textInput* for **firstName**, it should be focused on next *textInput*

```
const firstNameRef = useRef(null);
  const lastNameRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=> {
    firstNameRef.current.focus();
  }, [])

  const firstKeyPress = (e) => {
    if(e.key ==="Enter"){
      lastNameRef.current.focus();
    }    
  }
```

input.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextInput, View } from "react-native";

const Input = React.forwardRef(({placeholder,onKeyPress},ref) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <TextInput ref={ref} placeholder={placeholder}/>

    </View>
  )
})


export default Input;
```

Will I only add `blurOnSubmit={false} onSubmitEditing={()=>lastNameRef.current.focus()}` on **Input** component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it worked.
I only added `blurOnSubmit={false} onSubmitEditing={()=>lastNameRef.current.focus()}` for the first TextInput, and called it as props, in input.js as `blurOnSubmit={blurOnSubmit} onSubmitEditing={onsubmitEditing}`
When i press on Enter while in first TextInput, it goes to other input.